Magnetic field of a uniformly moving charge paradox
Suppose we have 2 charges $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ in a constant $\vec{r}$ distance from each other.
Now lets calculate force of magnetic field for each of them.
$\overrightarrow{\mathbb{F}_{12}} = \frac{q_{1}q_{2}}{c^{2} r_{12}^{3}}\left[ \vec{v_{2}}\left[ \vec{v_{1}},\vec{r_{12}} \right] \right]$,
$\overrightarrow{\mathbb{F}_{21}} = \frac{q_{2}q_{1}}{c^{2} r_{21}^{3}}\left[ \vec{v_{1}}\left[ \vec{v_{2}},\vec{r_{21}} \right] \right]$,
where $\vec{v_{1}}$ and $\vec{v_{2}}$ are their velocities. If they have equal, collinear velocities with same direction, the magnetic force will be
${\mathbb{F}_{M}} = \frac{q_{1}q_{2}}{c^{2} r^{2}}{v^{2}} \neq 0$.
Say $\vec{v_{1}}=\vec{v_{2}}=0$, folows ${\mathbb{F}_{M}} = 0$. This means,  that changing of inertial system can cause some new forces to be created (as I know it can not happen for inertial systems). Please explain why is it so, and if I am wrong somewhere please correct me.

The magnetic lorentz force itself is not covariant under the change of coordinates, but the total force(general lorentz force) including the electric force=qE is covariant. This is one of the assumptions in the special theory of relativity.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The force between two charges has both an electric and magnetic component. The total force must be calculated using
$${\bf F} = q({\bf E} + {\bf v}\times {\bf B})\ ,$$
where the E- and B-fields are those due to the other particle.
If you change frame of reference then in general the E- and B-fields must be transformed. Like all other vectors, they are not invariant.
A new force can be calculated in the new frame of reference
$${\bf F'} = q({\bf E'} + {\bf v'}\times {\bf B'})\ ,$$
and, in general, ${\bf F'}\neq {\bf F}$, because force is also not an invariant in different frames of reference.
